# Why won't `max_connections` update?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I'm using MySQL 5.7.29 on Ubuntu 16.04.  I'd like to increase the number of connections allowed by the MySQL server.  This involves setting configuration for both MySQL and Ubuntu.

**MySQL**

The primary config parameter is MySQL's `max_connections`.  I've edited `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` to have

```
max_connections = 800
```

(previously it was commented out and set to 100).  I also need to make sure that `table-open-cache` is high enough; for our application that's about `2 x max_connections` plus a little extra.  `$ mysqld --verbose --help` reports

```
table-open-cache                2000
```

which should be high enough.

**Ubuntu**

For every open connection, MySQL opens a placeholder file for it.  Thus, in addition to increasing MySQL's `max_connections`, I need to make sure that the OS allows the MySQL process to open a sufficient number of files.

Existing answers for doing this divide into `systemd` and non-`systemd` approaches.  This system uses `systemd`.

*non-systemd*

The non-`systemd` approach involves editing `/etc/security/limits.conf`.  I followed instructions for doing this before I learned that `systemd` ignores this file for this case.  The original version of this question concerned that effort; I've edited it to remove what I now know is irrelevant.  I'm happy to restore information about what I did if anyone thinks it's relevant.  Long story short is that I successfully increased the output of `$ ulimit -n` from 1024 to 16384.

*systemd*

Raising the number of files MySQL can open on `systemd` requires editing the MySQL service file.

The `systemd` MySQL service file on this system is `/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service`.  Rather than editing the file directly, which I understand is bad practice, I created the directory `/etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d/` and the file `override.conf` within it.  To `override.conf`, I added

```
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=65536
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
```

I also added `fs.file-max = 65536` to `/etc/sysctl.conf`, though I'm still not clear on what relation that file has to `systemd` or whether it has any effect on a `systemd` system.

I reloaded `systemd` config (`$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload`) and MySQL (`$ sudo service mysql restart`).

Checking to see if it worked, I note that `$ service mysql status` indicates that the new `override.conf` file is being recognized:

```
$ sudo service mysql status
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d
           └─override.conf
...
```

However, MySQL continues to report a value of 151 for `max_connections`:

```
$ sudo mysqld --verbose --help | grep max-connections
  --max-connections=# The number of simultaneous clients allowed
max-connections                                              151
```

(I get the same result checking `mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_connections'` from within the interactive MySQL shell).

What else do I need to do to permanently increase `max_connections`?

Comment: Did you ever find out the solution to your issue?

Comment: @JohnK.N.  As far as I can tell from my notes, the problem was that MySQL on Ubuntu is a user-hostile tangle of nearly half a million different config files all symlinked to each other, and I was editing the wrong one because that's the one everyone said to edit.  Editing `/etc/alternatives/my.cnf` instead of `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` caused MySQL to recognize the update.  This was for Ubuntu 16.04; things appear to have changed yet again for 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's verify that it is looking at that file.  Run

```
mysqld --help --verbose | more
```

and look for something like

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

Then I will question the need for 800.  Do you have hundreds of clients that want to stay connected?  Hopefully, they are *willing* to reconnect; after all, network glitches *do* happen.  Is the `wait_timeout` set high?  Perhaps too high.

Answer (score 0):

**Welcome**.

As per MySQL Documentation, your MySQL server does not have enough resources.

Also go through this

> The table_open_cache and max_connections system variables affect the
>   maximum number of files the server keeps open. If you increase one or
>   both of these values, you may run up against a limit imposed by your
>   operating system on the per-process number of open file descriptors.

Comment: Yes.  You've essentially restated the premise of my question.

Comment: Also, please note that you shall look at OS settings for per-process number of open file descriptions. Once that is increased, you shall see higher value here too.

Comment: The accepted answer to this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55319/are-limits-conf-values-applied-on-a-per-process-basis indicates that the limits.conf settings I've already (successfully) increased are per-process.  Do you have a more detailed idea in mind that you might share?